# Combining Swinxyzoom plugin with Fancybox in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, zooming

What I'm trying to achieve is to activate the Swinxyzoom Wordpress plugin (which uses jQuery to allow the user to zoom into a part of an image) within a Fancybox lightbox on a responsive website.

After getting in contact with the Swinxyzoom plugin author, he sugested the following:

> To integrate SwinxyZoom with a lightbox you will need to create some
>   custom code which is triggered when the lightbox has finished
>   displaying its content, eg. in fancybox this event is ‘onComplete’.
>
> At this point you need to wrap the content image of the lightbox with
>   an anchor tag targeting the large full image and then initialise
>   swinxyzoom as $(element).swinxyzoom();

Any help would be much appreciated!

The test page of the site on which I've used both of the above plugins individually is http://www.mcemcourses.org/radiology-test

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided, this code should do the trick :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery('a.myfancybox').fancybox({
        'zoomSpeedIn': 500,
        'zoomSpeedOut': 500,
        'overlayShow': true,
        'overlayOpacity': 0.3,
        'onComplete': function () {
            $("#fancybox-img").wrap("<a class='myZoom' href='http://www.mcemcourses.org/wp-content/uploads/9-Orbital-floor-.jpg' />");
            $("a.myZoom").swinxyzoom({
                mode: 'lens' // or your preferred mode
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Notice** that you will need 3 images :

- Your thumbnail, the one you click to open fancybox.
- A middle size image, the one you target in the `href` of the link that opens fancybox, and actually, the image opened in fancybox.
- A big size image, the one you set in the `href` of the wrapping anchor inside the `onComplete` callback.

Also notice that the selector `#fancybox-img` refers to the opened image in fancybox for v1.3.x only.

**NOTE** : Most popular fancybox WordPress plugins use v1.3.4.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C9Eza/)**

Comment: Thankyou for your response. Forgive my ignorance but would I add this javascript to the onComplete event in the mcemcourses.org/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery-optimizer/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js file?

Comment: @Shaun : you don't need to mess with the original fancybox js or css files. You set this in your already existing custom script (where you defined `.myfancybox` selector) in the `<head>` section of your page.